# Create HTML from JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

Here I have sme .ajax function that work well:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
$('a#kom').click(function (e) {
    var tabela = 'parcele';
      $.ajax({
            url: "getComments.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true, 
            data: { ajdi:ajdi,tabela:tabela}, //your form data to post goes here as a json object
            dataType: "html",

            success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);  
            },
            error:function(data) {
            console.log(data); 
            }
        });

        });
        });
```

and this function produce this JSON:

```
[{"datum":"2014-05-22","komentar":"Testiranje za komentare da vidimo kako moze da sluzi, dali radidobro, bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ... ..."}]
```

Iknow its a basic question but I cant find any good resource... How I can into .ajax function when function is success to create this html:

```
'<div class="notes">
        <h4>Tekst zaglavlje</h4>
        <h5>'+datum+'</h5>
        <p>'+komentar+'</p>
    </div>'
```

for every object I get from JSON... so like that:

```
            success: function(data) {
            // CREATE A HTML FROM JSON DATA FOR EACH JSON OBJECT. HOW?
            console.log(data);  
            },
```

**UPDATE WITH PHP**

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') { 

    try {


     $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM komentari WHERE id_utabeli=:ajdi AND tabela=:tabela");
     $result->execute(array(':ajdi' => $_POST['ajdi'], ':tabela' => $_POST['tabela']));
    $result = $result->fetchAll(); 

     $temp = array();
foreach($result as $r) {

          $temp[] = array('datum' => (string) $r['datum'], 'komentar' => (string) $r['komentar']); 

        }
    $table = $temp;
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo $jsonTable;
}
    else { 
echo 'ERROR 404';
  }
```

Comment: Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a wrong dataType that should be:

```
dataType: "json",
```

because response is **`json`** not a **`html`**.

In your success function do this:

```
success: function(data) {
    var htm = '';  
    $.each(data, function(i, resp){
        htm +='<div class="notes">' + 
                 '<h4>Tekst zaglavlje</h4>' +
                 '<h5>'+resp.datum+'</h5>' +
                 '<p>'+resp.komentar+'</p>' +
             '</div>';
    }); 
    $('yourContainer').html(htm);
},
```

---

As your response seems to be an array `[{},{}....]` or multiple javascript objects so to produce such `html` markup you have to loop in that array with `$.each()` method and declare one blank `var htm='';` before `$.each()` iteration and concatenate the resulting html out of your json, then place at the position of your container which can hold the produced html.

---

#### [Find a Demo @ Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dA3X/)

Comment: I get; Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '162' in [{"datum":"2014-05-22","komentar":"Testiranje za komentare da vidimo kako moze da sluzi, dali radidobro, bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ... ..."}]

Comment: why this is not a safe way, open XSS?

Comment: Then you have posted a wrong json object. Then it might be `{},{}...` instead of `[{}, {} ...]`.

Comment: @gmaestro why do you have a `dataType: "html"`? Wouldn't it be `"json"`.

Comment: Is this now a safe way to create HTML from JSON?

Comment: @gmaestro How this is opened to xss attacks? If you externalize your scripts then what is the way to open it for these attacks.

Comment: How yu think to externalize ?

Comment: @gmaestro see dataType is used to tell the function that coming response from server is a json if set to `"json"` otherwise there will be a error.

Comment: **exernalize** is saving scripts in a separate js file and include it and xss are opened if you have used some js events in your markup as a inline scripts events like `onclick, onsubmit etc.`

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using jquery, you can do this like follows:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('a#kom').click(function (e) {
        var tabela = 'parcele';
        $.ajax({
            url: "getComments.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true, 
            data: { ajdi: ajdi, tabela: tabela },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);  

                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    // create html
                    var elem = '<div class="notes">
                                    <h4>Tekst zaglavlje</h4>
                                    <h5>' + item.datum + '</h5>
                                    <p>' + item.komentar + '</p>
                                </div>'

                    $('body').append(elem); // append the item
                });
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: say: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: I change only this: $('#komenatri').append(elem);

Comment: extended it a little bit. please try again.

Comment: what that means: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '162' in [{"datum":"2014-05-22","komentar":"Testiranje za komentare da vidimo kako moze da sluzi, dali radidobro, bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ... ..."}]

Comment: changed the code. it was not expecting json thus data was not an object. now it should work.

Comment: Why is this not a safe way, open XSS?

Comment: You insert text into the page generated by another script without escaping it. See: https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/cross-site-scripting/

Comment: unsafe comments should be escaped before they are saved in your db. So your return json data shouldn't contain malicious strings anyway.

Comment: @sjkm You should still html escape here too to be safe. Better safe than sorry ;) Regardless of what *should* have been escaped by now... sticking strings together is not the proper way to set the text of an element in JQuery. That's what the ````.text()```` method is for. http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2

Answer (score 1):

Your success function should look like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    notes_div = $("<div/>");
    hfour = $("<h4/>").text("Tekst zaglavlje");
    hfive = $("<h5/>").text(data.datum);
    para = $("<p/>").text(data.komentar);
    notes_div.append(hfour).append(hfive).append(para);
    $('#komenatri').append();
},
```

Other answers provided that just build your HTML as a string are not safe. They open you up to XSS (google it ;) )  but we fix that by making elements as JQuery objects and setting their `.text()` which makes the resultant content HTML safe.

You should also run your data through `htmlspecialchars()` in PHP before outputing it.

change:

```
$temp[] = array('datum' => (string) $r['datum'], 'komentar' => (string) $r['komentar']);
```

To

```
$temp[] = array('datum' => htmlspecialchars( (string) $r['datum'] ), 'komentar' => htmlspecialchars( (string) $r['komentar']) );
```

This will prevent users from injecting their own HTML into your pages with their comments.

Comment: yes but this is incomplete answer, becuse I need to make html for every JSON object also I need to add it into ID=komentari

Comment: hm, dont ork, just nothing happend... is there some sintaks error?

Comment: @gmaestro I've changed my answer so that the resultant HTML goes into '#komentri' can you clarify. What do you mean by every object returned? in the success function does ````data```` contain info for one form or all forms??

Comment: @gmaestro you tell me. If you open your web developer console do you get an error? Does an element with the id 'komenatri' exist?

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data) {
    for(var i = 0, ceiling = data.length; i < ceiling; i++) {
        document.getElementById("komenatri").innerHTML += 
            "<div class=\"notes\"><h4>Tekst zaglavje</hr><h5>" + 
            data[i].datum + 
            "</h5><p>" + 
            data[i].komentar + 
            "</p></div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but I'd imagine it's because you've provided a pure JavaScript onlclick answer when what's needed is clearly a JQuery one with an AJAX success function. Bit nasty not leave a comment first though...